# How to fetch PAN number from GST number - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a Flutter app where I need to extract the PAN number from a GST number that the user enters. I want the app to automatically fetch the PAN number from the provided GST number and display it in a text field.this code is implemented by me  help of AI Tools in flutter.

```
  
> **define controller for textfield**

    TextEditingController gstController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController panController = TextEditingController();
    String _panNumber = '';

> **function of fetch pan number**

    String extractPANNumber(String input) {
    List<String> patterns = ["[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}"];

    for (var pattern in patterns) {
    RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
    Iterable<Match> matches = regExp.allMatches(input);
    for (var match in matches) {
      return match.group(0) ?? '';
     }
    }
    return "PAN number not found";
    }

    void _updatePAN(String gstNumber) {
    String? panNumber = extractPANNumber(gstNumber);
    setState(() {
     _panNumber = panNumber;
    panController.text = panNumber;
    });
    print('PAN no = ${panController.text}');
    }

   @override
   void dispose() {
   gstController.dispose();
   panController.dispose();
   super.dispose();
   }
```

Comment: First 2 digits are the State code of the registered person. The next 10 chars are the PAN number. Once the user enters the GST number , just extract the GST string starting from 2 to 12: ``gst.substring(2, 12);`` will give you PAN number.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getPanFromGst(String gst)
{
    if (gst.length() != 15)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid GST Number, Must be 15 charcters ("+gst+")");
    String pan = gst.substring(2,12);
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char c = pan.charAt(i);
        boolean alphaExpected = i < 5 || i==9;
        if (alphaExpected && (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') || (!alphaExpected && (c < '0' || c > '9')))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("PAN number extracted is invalid : "+pan);
    }
    return pan;
}
```